# FormatDate() AMPscript function not showing 'minutes'

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, datetime

I have an attribute named `ClassStartDateTime` in a data extension with a value of:

```
Wednesday, April 19, 2017 9:00 AM
```

I'd like to extract only the time from this attribute using the `FormatDate()` function.

```
SET @class_starttime = FormatDate(ClassStartDateTime, 'h:mm tt')
```

Any idea why the month is being pulled in instead of the minute? The output looks like this:

> 9:04 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered after a support ticket...

The FormatDate() function will always be looking for a Month/year and minute. So in order to exclude one or more of the parts, you need to include a empty set of ''

So the formatting will look like this:

```
Set @class_start_time = FormatDate(ClassStartTime,'','h:mm tt')
```